# Why do different packages have the same version?

Tags: apt, python3

A bot detects changes in Ubuntu packages and triggers a new installation of the package. Currently, the installation is failing since the bot tries to install a specific version of the package which does not seem to exist:

```shell
$ apt-get update
...
Reading package lists... Done

$ apt-get install python3=3.10.6-1~22.04.1 -y
...
E: Version '3.10.6-1~22.04.1' for 'python3' was not found
```

Looking at [python3 packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3.10), version `3.10.6-1~22.04.1` is listed and it also [appears in launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.10/3.10.6-1%7E22.04.1).

Strangely, when the version constraint is dropped, `apt-get` installs the package `3.10.6-1~22.04.1`

```shell
$ apt-get install python3 -y
...
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 [2263 kB]
...
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10 amd64 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 [497 kB]
...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.1) ...
...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.6-1~22.04.1) ...
```

Although the package name is `3.10.6-1~22.04.1` its version is `3.10.6-1~22.04`

```shell
$ dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' python3
3.10.6-1~22.04

$ apt-cache show python3 | grep Version | head -n 1
Version: 3.10.6-1~22.04
```

Is this a bug that package [3.10.6-1~22.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.10/3.10.6-1%7E22.04) and [3.10.6-1~22.04.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.10/3.10.6-1%7E22.04.1) have the same version? If not, a clarification on the matter will be great.

Comment: Maybe this particular package was incorrectly named (or incorrectly versioned)? Have you seen any other examples of this behaviour?

Comment: @Greenonline I have yet came across other examples. Yet, do you think the package was versioned incorrectly?

Comment: I really don't know, but, as you point out, there is a mismatch in the name and version info - maybe this is deliberate (or a limitation of some sort)? I looked into it a bit: [Understanding Debian dpkg package version numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96599/97255) but didn't look too hard and didn't find anything obvious.

Comment: Hmmm. It might indeed be a bug. The the [changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/python3.10/python3.10_3.10.6-1~22.04.1/changelog) shows that .1 is a security update pushed several weeks ago, and the Ubuntu Security Team's [CVE Tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-42919) agrees. Were I in your position, I would [email the Ubuntu Security Team directly](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-hardened) with this question about what happened to the .1 patched version.